# Lookup speed: State or Database?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have a bunch of wordlists on a server of mine, and I've been planning to make a simple open-source JSON API that returns if a password is on the list<sup>1</sup>, as a method of validation. I'm doing this in Python with Flask, and literally just returning if input is present.

One small problem: the wordlists total about 150 million entries, and 1.1GB of text.

My API (minimal) is below. Is it more efficient to store every row in MongoDB and look up repeatedly, or to store the entire thing in memory using a singleton, and populate it on startup when I call `app.run`? Or are the differences subjective?
Furthermore, is it even good practice to do the latter? I'm thinking the lookups might start to become taxing if I open this to the public. I've also had someone suggest a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for efficient searching.

**Update:** I've done a bit of testing, and document searching is painfully slow with such a high number of records. Is it justifiable to use a database with proper indexes for a single column of data that needs to be efficiently searched?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.views import MethodView
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
mongo = PyMongo(app)

class HashCheck(MethodView):

  def post(self):
    return json.dumps({'result' : 
      not mongo.db.passwords.find({'pass' : request.form["password"])})
    # Error-handling + test cases to come. Negate is for bool.

  def get(self):
    return redirect('/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.add_url_rule('/api/', view_func=HashCheck.as_view('api'))
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

<sub>1: I'm a security nut. I'm using it in my login forms and rejecting common input. One of the wordlists is UNIQPASS.</sub>

Comment: Since the list is static, it could be stored in memory.

But if you are going to use MongoDB, be sure to do a Covered Query: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.indexOnly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would suggest is a hybrid approach.  As requests are made do two checks.  The first in a local cache and the the second in the MongoDB store.  If the first fails but the second succeeds then add it to the in memory cache.  Over time the application will "fault" in the most common "bad passwords"/records.

This has two advantages:
1) The common words are rejected very fast from within memory.
2) The startup cost is close to zero and amortized over many queries.

When storing the word list in MongoDB I would make the _id field hold each word. By default you will get a ObjectId which is a complete waste in this case. We can also then leverage the automatic index on _id. I suspect the poor performance you saw was due to there not being an index on the 'pass' field.  You can also try adding one on the 'pass' field with:

```
mongo.db.passwords.create_index("pass")
```

To complete the _id scenario: to insert a word:

```
mongo.db.passwords.insert( { "_id" : "password" } );
```

Queries then look like:

```
mongo.db.passwords.find( { "_id" : request.form["password"] } )
```

As @Madarco mentioned you can also shave another bit off the query time by ensuring results are returned from the index by limiting the returned fields to just the _id field (`{ "_id" : 1}`).

```
mongo.db.passwords.find( { "_id" : request.form["password"] }, { "_id" : 1} )
```

HTH - Rob

P.S. I am not a Python/Pymongo expert so might not have the syntax 100% correct.  Hopefully it is still helpful.

Comment: It certainly helps, and I'm going to do some final testing before I push this into beta tomorrow. Startup cost could definitely be a factor, as this is on a box that does other things, too. If this ever gets extreme load, I'll probably consider rewriting it in C with CGI and doing proper alloc like John the Ripper et al, but I prefer the more readable languages.

Comment: @Hiroto: Start-up will be greatly faster. You can also *test* this approach faster and more easily and on smaller machines. You can modify this approach with a LRU cache of a fixed size (which will give you most of the benefits for a guaranteed memory size, say 80% of the performance for 200MB). You can also use different backends (Mongo, Redis or even SQL). It matters even less which one you use when you have a cache in front of it.

Answer (score 4):

Given that your list is totally static and fits in memory, I don't see a compelling reason to use a database.

I agree that a Trie would be efficient for your goal.  A hash table would work too.

PS: it's too bad about Python's Global Interpreter Lock.  If you used a language with real multithreading,  you could take advantage of the unchanging data structure and run the server across multiple cores with shared memory.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out and trying redis as an option too. Its fast, very fast, and has nice python bindings. I would try to create a set in redis of the word list, then use the `SISMEMBER` function to check if the word is in the set. `SISMEMBER` is an O(1) operation, so it should be faster than a mongo query.

Thats assuming you want the whole list in memory of course, and that you are willing to do away with the mongo. . .

Here's more info on redis's [SISMEMBER](http://redis.io/commands/sismember), and the [python bindings](http://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
for redis

Comment: I was mostly looking for ease of use/adding wordlists when i chose mongo; i could just load the entire thing into memory in python and use `password in wordlist` with a slave state thread, but that has high costs at startup, and consumes 1.5GB RAM (I have 16GB on my primary, but it's still a sizable chunk for my 2GB slave)

Comment: yeah, the redis option would be a memory sink, but there would also be no costs at startup. Adding/removing things in redis sets is easy too, and there are some other features like unions etc too.

Comment: Also, the redis DB could be on a totally different box of course, which would free up some memory on the app server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [kyotocabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/), it's very fast. I've used it in similar circumstances:

```
import kyotocabinet as kyc

from flask import Flask
from flask.views import MethodView
import json

app = Flask(__name__)


dbTree = kyc.DB()

if not dbTree.open('./passwords.kct', DB.OREADER):
    print >>sys.stderr, "open error: " + str(dbTree.error())
    raise SystemExit


app = Flask(__name__)


class HashCheck(MethodView):

  def post(self):
    return json.dumps({'result' : 
      dbTree.check(request.form["password"]) > 0 })
    # Error-handling + test cases to come. Negate is for bool.

  def get(self):
    return redirect('/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.add_url_rule('/api/', view_func=HashCheck.as_view('api'))
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```